# Stack around p was corrupted c++

Tags: c++, string, char

It must be pretty simple but i am so numb right now to think clearly.
So this is a small part of my code everything works fine except this.
What i actually wanted to do is infile1.open(temp2->path); but it's not possible since temp2 is a string. So i want to put this string into a char array like char p[100] to use infile1.open(p). It compiles but after some seconds boom: Stack around p was corrupted

```
   char p[100];
   while( temp2 != 0)
   {
        stringToCharArray(temp2->path, p); 
        infile1.open(p);
        checkingWords(infile1, stopWords, invertedIndex);
        infile1.close();
        temp2 = temp2->next;
   }


void stringToCharArray(string s, char *c)
{
    int i;
    int size = s.size();
    for( i=0; i<=size ; i++)
    {
        c[i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't null terminate. And is your path longer than 99 characters?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

```
infile1.open(temp2->path.c_str());
```

(Be careful, this `const char *` is only valid until the next time you change something in the `std::string` you get it from, in this case `temp2->path`).

It looks like the main error with your existing code is `for( i=0; i<=size ; i++)` should be `i<size`. But let's not go into that in too much detail, as you shouldn't really do it this way anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the easy way

```
infile1.open(temp2->path.c_str());
```

But your hard way should look like this

```
void stringToCharArray(string s, char *c)
{
    int i;
    int size = s.size();
    for( i=0; i<size ; i++) // < not <=
    {
        c[i] = s[i];
    }
    c[size] = '\0';
}
```

Of course the hard way is going to fail if your string happens to be 100 characters or more.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
 infile1.open(temp2->path.c_str());
```

The stack corruption occurs inside your `stringToCharArray` function.

```
for( i=0; i<=size ; i++)
            //^^^should not reach size-1, equal redundant
```